# How to get coordinates of a view in constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, coordinates

I have an `ImageView` in the center of a constraint layout. I want to get its coordinates in the screen for animation. **I have referred similar questions**, but I always get 0 as the coordinate.

How can I get the coordinates?

***What I have tried:***

```
imageView.getTop();  

imageView.getX();

imageView.getPivotX();

Rect rect = new Rect();
imageView.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);
rect.centerX()
```

***Note:***
`ImageView` is placed at the center using constraints and it is of dimension 40dp x 40dp (small image).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack I have already referred that question. Can you kindly specify which methods to use, if any works.

Comment: the second answer looks like it should work.  I have used similar code. if that does not work, this might:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034097/how-to-get-a-views-coordinates-in-constraintlayout